# the short-written rules of using "_" in scala anonymous function confused me

Tags: scala

I have two kinds of definition of a three-parameter function as below:

```
val minus1: (Int, Int, Int) => Int = _ - _ - _
val minus2: (Int, Int, Int) => Int = （_ - _） - _
```

minus1 is fine, but minus2 is reported illegal, that confused me a lot

Following ComDubh's insturction, i write a new function like:

```
val minus3 : (Int, Int, Int)=>Int = ((_-_)-_)
```

why this was still wrong? Did that mean i shouldn't put any parenthese between the "_"s?
and i have a more complicated question like

```
val func4: Int=>Int = x => if (x>0) 1 else -1
val func5: Int=>Int = if (_>0) 1 else -1
```

func4 is good, but why i can't omit the parametr name "x" to rewrite the function as func5(the compiler regards the 1 or -1 as the return value and reports Int(1) doesn't fit Int=>Int). Thans for your time

Comment: The meaning of `_` changes inside parentheses.

Comment: Personal advice, don't use the `_` for nothing that isn't trivial like `foos.map(_.bar)` or `foo.reduce(_ + _)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an anonymous function. Scala has to know where the definition of the anonymous function starts and ends. Your use of parentheses in `minus2` tells Scala that `_ - _` is the complete function. The compiler isn't happy of course as you're missing an argument.

Comment: I realized that's a question about rules to determine the scope of underscore.  thanks very much